# C# confuses Vector3 for Vector2 in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

While trying to make the pivot of a sprite the same position as the cursor - Vector3 objPos - and instantiating objects from the cursor position minus some difference - Vector3 diff - Unity threw an error that says "Operator '-' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector2' and 'Vector3'" even tho the both variables are Vector3's

```
public Transform baseDot;
public KeyCode mouseLeft;
public Vector2 mousePosition;
Vector2 mousePos;
Vector2 objPos;

void OnMouseOver()
{
    Vector3 diff = new Vector3(2f, 2.8f, 0f);
    float xPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos).x;
    float yPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos).y;
    mousePos = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    objPos = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, -10);

    if (Input.GetKey(mouseLeft) )
        Instantiate(baseDot, objPos-diff, baseDot.rotation);
}
```

Comment: You say both variables are a `Vector3`, however they are not.  You have declared `objPos` as a `Vector2`. Since Unity has an implicit operator which converts a `Vector2` to a `Vector3`, you won't get any compile time errors. Change the variable at the top of your script to a Vector3 and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even tho the both variables are Vector3's

That's not quite true since you defined

```
Vector2 objPos;
```

The `Vector3` value you assign to it is implicitly converted to a `Vector2` value.

It gets clear if you read the according API for [`Vector2.Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_Vector2.html)

> Converts a `Vector2` to a `Vector3`.
>
> A `Vector2` can be implicitly converted into a `Vector3`. (The `z` is set to zero in the result).

and [`Vector2.Vector2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_Vector3.html)

> Converts a `Vector3` to a `Vector2`.
>
> A `Vector3` can be implicitly converted into a `Vector2`. (The z is discarded).

where *implicit* means you don't have to explicitly use a typecast but can use both types exchangeably.

Read more about [implicit and explicit conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

So in the error you get `ambiguous` means c# doesn't know which operation you want to use.

Either `Vector2 - Vector2` or `Vector3 - Vector3` exist, both are possible due to the implicit conversion .. so c# doesn't know which of the two values to change the type for.

---

The most obvious solution is to change the type to

```
Vector3 objPos;
```

Answer (score 2):

C# behaves correctly here. Vector2 and Vector3 are structures (value types) and it is only possible to assign Vector3 to Vector2 because Vector2 has an implicite operator defined. This means that when you assign Vector3 to variable of type Vector2, it becomes Vector2 and the z coordinate is lost.

To resolve your issue, simply change the type of objPos to Vector3 or create a new temporary variable to store the new Vector3(xPos, yPos, -10);

To understand the behaviour, I would suggest to study reference vs value types and implicit operators.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to define variable objPos as **Vector3**, I am not sure if it has implicit/explicit cast operator defined between the types:

```
Vector2 objPos;
...
objPos = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, -10);
```